# Why doesn't (52 & (1 << 37)) return 0?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to make an algorithm that given an integer, spits out the string representation of its binary form.

Now, I'm basically comparing a mask to see where to append the 1/0 bits. This worked fine until slightly larger numbers appeared, e.g.: `(52 & (1 << 37))` which, if I understood the bitshift operator correctly (apparently I didn't) should return 0, because `(1 << 37)` = `1` and 37 * `0`'s. Now last time I checked, there are no 1's in the 38th place of the decimal `52` in binary format, so why does this return 32?

Comment: How many bits do you suppose [Java's int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) has?

Comment: BTW check out BigInteger, it has lots of operations that will make things easier for you, especially when you start to use numbers with more than 64 bits ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This entire expression is performed using 32 bit numbers because all of the operands are `int` values.

So therefore `1 << 37` is not a "one" followed by 37 "zero" bits.

In fact, [JLS 15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) says that the shift count is masked with `0x1f` (for the 32 bit shift operators).  Thus `1 << 37` actually means the same thing as `1 << 5`; i.e. a "one" followed by 5 "zero" bits.

If you want to use 64 bit integers in the shift expression, the first operand must be a `long`; i.e. `(52 & (1L << 37))`.

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed the amount of bits an int even stores.

Answer (score 1):

In java, Integer is a `32` bit representation (irrespective of 32 or 64 bit architecture).

The following will give a `0` as expected while `long` is used(`37` < `64`):

```java
    (52 & (1L << 37))
```

With `long`, the same problem will arise for a shift greater than `63` (more specifically greater than `(1 << 63) - 1)`)

Now considering why the answer is `32` with integer:

```java
   1 << 31 == Integer.MIN_VALUE
   
   (1 << 32) - 1 == 0

   1 << 32 == 1 == 2^(32 - 32) == 2^0

   1 << 33 == 2 == 2^(33 - 32) == 2^1

   1 << 34 == 4 == 2^(34 - 32) == 2^2
   
   1 << 37 == 32 == 2^(37 - 32) == 2^5
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the Java Language Specification says about [left-shifting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) (an older one, but these things do not change much) that

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

So when operating on 32-bit `int`s, the `<< 37` in your code becomes `<< 5`, and `52 & (1 << 5)` is really `32`.